# Recharts Bar Charts: Brush label is hiding when responsive containers end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, recharts

[Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oyjr.png)

The label/text of brush (date) is hiding due to responsive container end. I just want the label/text of brush overlaps everything so user can read it

```
  <Brush
            dataKey="dateCreated"
            height={20}
            stroke="#8884d8"
            style={{margin: "20px"}}
          />
```

I have tried giving z-index to svg elements but it didn't work. I'm looking for if i can make brush small so the date can be visible or i can make it overlapping everything.